# Merge cells with same data in adjacent rows over two columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to merge the cells with same data;

I would like to merge the cells with similar values as below in excel;

```
  |---------------------------|             |----------------------------|
  |Customer | FG | RPL   | DC |             |Customer | FG | RPL   | DC  |
  |---------+----+-------+----|             |---------+----+-------+-----|
  |A        | x  | alpha | 1  |             |A        | x  | alpha | 1   |
  |A        | x  | gamma | 5  |     ---->   |         |    | gamma | 5   |
  |A        | y  | alpha | 4  |             |         +----+-------+-----|
  |A        | y  | gamma | NA |             |         | y  | alpha | 4   |
  |B        | x  | gamma | 5  |             |         |    | gamma | NA  |
  |C        | x  | alpha | 1  |             |---------+----+-------+-----|
  |---------------------------|             |B        | x  | gamma | 5   |
                                            |---------+----+-------+-----|
                                            |C        | x  | alpha | 1   |
                                            |----------------------------|
```

I tried this code but it won't merge the second column.

```
Set Rng = Range("B2:B8")
xRows = Rng(Rng.Count).Row
For i = 1 To xRows - 1
    For j = i + 1 To xRows
        If Rng.Cells(i, 1).Value <> Rng.Cells(j, 1).Value Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Range("B2").Parent.Range(Rng.Cells(i, 1), Rng.Cells(j - 1, 1)).Merge

    'Merging 2nd column
    Set SubRng = Range("B2").Parent.Range(Rng.Cells(i, 2), Rng.Cells(j - 1, 2))
    MsgBox SubRng.Address
    SubxRows = SubRng(SubRng.Count).Row
    For l = i To SubxRows - 1
        For m = l + 1 To SubxRows
            If SubRng.Cells(l, 1).Value <> SubRng.Cells(m, 1).Value Then
                Exit For
            End If
            Range("B2").Parent.Range(SubRng.Cells(l, 1), SubRng.Cells(m - 1, 1)).Merge
        Next
    Next

Next
```

Comment: Merging cells is almost always a bad idea. Is there a real big need to do so? Adding your data as a table is perfectly fine, but adding column Letters can be helpfull

Comment: Actually yes, coz I need to be able to just filter the customer and see all the other fields simultaneously. Even the raw data i have given above is the result of combining 3 different table with a particular logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree with the comment from Luuklag, merging cells is slippery slope, you could put your data into a **pivot table** and then just format it.

Also

```
Set Rng = Range("B2:B21")
xRows = Rng(Rng.Count).Row
For i = 1 To xRows - 1
For j = i + 1 To xRows
    If Rng.Cells(i, 1).Value <> Rng.Cells(j, 1).Value Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next
Range("B2").Parent.Range(Rng.Cells(i, 1), Rng.Cells(j - 1, 1)).Merge

'Merging 2nd column
Set SubRng = Range("B2").Parent.Range(Rng.Cells(i, 2), Rng.Cells(j - 1, 2))
i = j - 1 ' dirty fix jumping i to correct range
MsgBox SubRng.Address
SubxRows = SubRng(SubRng.Count).Row
For l = xI To SubxRows - 1
    For m = l + 1 To SubxRows
        If m > SubRng.Count Then Exit For

        If SubRng.Cells(l, 1).Value <> SubRng.Cells(m, 1).Value Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
     Range("B2").Parent.Range(SubRng.Cells(l, 1), SubRng.Cells(m - 1, 1)).Merge ' moved this line
Next

Next
```

The merge code needed to be outside of the "For" loop, just tested it and realized your loops need a tweak added a dirty quick fix to jump variable "i", this should work now.

Comment: you are the savior. I assume xI in your code is typo and corrected it to 1 and the result works like a charm! Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd advice you not to merge anything and keep your data in place while properly formatting them to mimic merge

as follows (assuming data in B2:E8, and headers in B2:E2)

```
Option Explicit

Sub MimicMerge()

    With Range("C3:E8").FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$C3<>$C2")
        .Borders(xlTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .StopIfTrue = False
    End With

    With Range("C3:C8").FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND($C3=$C2;$B3=$B2)")
        .Font.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .StopIfTrue = False
    End With

    With Range("B3:E8").FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$B3<>$B2")
        .Borders(xlTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .StopIfTrue = False
    End With

    With Range("B3:B8").FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$B3=$B2")
        .Font.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .StopIfTrue = False
    End With

End Sub
```

before

[image]

after

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Hey @DisplayName How about the second column? Similar elements there need to be merged as well for the respective customer....
Also you solution seems like the data needs to be all in fixed places. My actual data is dynamic and the range may vary. Thanks for taking a look anyways.

Comment: 1) _"How about the second column? Similar elements there need to be merged as well for the respective customer"_: the "after" image was wrong, I edited with the correct image, while the code stays ok. 2) _"Also you solution seems like the data needs to be all in fixed places."_: my solution expects data as you showed them in your question example (left of the arrow). So you may want to try it and then watch what happens

Comment: Thank you! But i was looking for a dynamic code and @Ricards solution is inline with my code! Thanks again for your time and an innovative solution :)

Comment: You are welcome. But could you explain what’s dynamic in Ricards solution that isn’t in mine? Thank you

Comment: After i just tried your macro, i see that it only removes the duplicates but does not actually merge! Also could you explain what is the actual logic applied here?
By dynamic i mean the my data range is not restricted to number of rows and columns and variables. It actually varies and when i tried your macro over a different data set it did not produce result as expected!
Here are some of data samples
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FQ09baQkJ8jZyvvqzQCThVzpzwqWsm-i/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: 1) _" i see that it only removes the duplicates but does not actually merge! "_ -> that's my exact answer preface _"I'd advice you not to merge anything and keep your data in place while properly formatting them to mimic merge"_ Data are kept in place and only "hidden" to mimic merge operation. Merging is something you want to avoid as much as possible

Comment: 2) _"Also could you explain what is the actual logic applied here?"_ ->  Data are kept in place and only "hidden" to _mimic_ merge operation. Merging is something you want to avoid as much as possible

Comment: 3) _"By dynamic i mean the my data range is not restricted to number of rows and columns and variables."_ just adjust range references to your need. Just as you have to do with Ricards code (where it assumes a hard coded `Range("B2:B21")` range

Comment: 4) " i tried your macro over a different data set it did not produce result as expected! " you only have to set the range references accordingly (as you have to do with Ricard code). For example, for your first data sample on the left you have to change all "8"s to "13"s (i.e. change `With Range("C3:E8")...` to `With Range("C3:E13")`, and so on)

Comment: Ahh... I see the intention behind this macro. It works after correcting the range. This could definitely be useful. But in my case merge is like inevitable. The idea is that when you merge i can easily select all the details needed for a specific customer and the presentation in report is attractive.
But i have to say your code is indeed quick and elegant. Definitely a thumbs up :) Thanks again!

Comment: you are welcome. but let me tell you once more that _merge is hell_ !

Answer (score 0):

Try this code (necessary comments in code):

```
Sub MergeCells()
    ' to prevent warnings from showing - we would get when merging
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, firstColumn As Long, firstRow As Long, startMergeRow1 As Long, startMergeRow2 As Long
    ' first column is A
    firstColumn = 1
    ' data starts in second row
    firstRow = 2
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, firstColumn).End(xlUp).Row
    startMergeRow1 = firstRow
    startMergeRow2 = firstRow

    For i = 2 To lastRow
        ' if values in first column differ, then merge first and second column
        If Cells(i, firstColumn) <> Cells(i + 1, firstColumn) Then
            Range(Cells(startMergeRow1, firstColumn), Cells(i, firstColumn)).Merge
            Range(Cells(startMergeRow2, firstColumn + 1), Cells(i, firstColumn + 1)).Merge
            startMergeRow1 = i + 1
            startMergeRow2 = i + 1
        ' if values in second column differ, then merge only second column
        ElseIf Cells(i, firstColumn + 1) <> Cells(i + 1, firstColumn + 1) Then
            Range(Cells(startMergeRow2, firstColumn + 1), Cells(i, firstColumn + 1)).Merge
            startMergeRow2 = i + 1
        End If
    Next

    ' turn showing warnings on again
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
End Sub
```